# use libhugetlbfs "Using hugepages for malloc" in container cause Bus Error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, huge-pages

I use k8s running program

According to this [HOWTO](https://github.com/libhugetlbfs/libhugetlbfs/blob/master/HOWTO), every command used libhugetlbfs in pod  cause bus error:

```
# LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libhugetlbfs.so HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes tail -f aaa.conf
Bus error (core dumped)

# cat /proc/sys/vm/nr_overcommit_hugepages
300000000
```

But when I enter mount namespace use `nsenter -m --target $PID`, and execute this command, it works well

I did find a relevant question like this, I've tried to add capabilities, privilege, runAsUser root and other, but no use

```
      securityContext:
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
        capabilities:
          add:
          - SYS_ADMIN
          - IPC_LOCK
        privileged: true
        runAsUser: 0
```

Did I missing something, and what causes this problem?

Comment: You probably need some higher privs, either a specific capability flag or privileged mode? The whole project far predates containers as a thing so it may not work at all.

Comment: i add privileged: true, capabilities.add: [SYS_ADMIN, IPC_LOCK], but still not working

Comment: Sounds like this just isn't compatible with container tech then. Might be doable if you dig through your core dumps and see exactly what is failing but might not be worth it.